# Why won't git run after install? Mac can't find it

Tags: git, macos

For some reason the terminal can't run git even though it's installed where it should be. Any ideas?

```
Samuels-MBP:/ pianomansb$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Samuels-MBP:/ pianomansb$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
Samuels-MBP:/ pianomansb$ git
-bash: /usr/bin/git: No such file or directory
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/666086/issues-installing-git-under-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks

Comment: See that when you type git it actually points to `/usr/bin/git` instead of local

Comment: derp i think i just needed to restart terminal. Sorry, and thanks